# Cant find bone constraint in blender 2.8?

Tags: rigging, bones

Im trying to have 1 bone copy the rotation of another, and aside from this https://blenderartists.org/t/no-bone-constraints-in-2-8b/1136765/4 I can't find anything on the topic - there doesn't seem to be a bone constraints tab in this version of 2.8.

[image: rig]

Where is this?

Comment: There is a problem about bone constraint in blender even in pose mode https://youtu.be/VcGM14fa6E0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be in pose mode to get access to the bone constraint tab (even in 2.79).

[image]